# This Oracle SQL SELECT shouldn't work. Why does it?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am debugging a query in Oracle 19c that is trying to sort a `SELECT DISTINCT` result by a field not in the query. (*Note: This is the wrong way to do it. Do not do this.*)

This query is trying to return a unique list of customer names sorted with the most recent sale date first. It returns an expected error, "ORA-01791: not a SELECTed expression".

```
SELECT DISTINCT CUSTOMER_NAME
FROM SALES
ORDER BY LAST_SALE_DATE DESCENDING;
```

It returns an error because the query is trying to order the result by a field that has not been selected. This makes sense so far.

However, if I simply add `FETCH FIRST 6 ROWS ONLY` to the query, it does *not* return an error (although the result is not correct so do not do this). But the question is why Oracle does not return an error message?

```
SELECT DISTINCT CUSTOMER_NAME
FROM SALES
ORDER BY LAST_SALE_DATE DESCENDING
FETCH FIRST 6 ROWS ONLY;
```

Why does adding `FETCH FIRST 6 ROWS ONLY` make this work?

Added: The incorrect query will return duplicates if there are multiple records with the same name and date. A search for something like "sql select distinct order by another column" will show several correct ways to do this.

Comment: I will assume you are right that that type of ordering should not be done. But if you are going to repeatedly tell us not to, a brief statement *why* would be useful.

Comment: @ejkeep - If you search for something like "sql select distinct order by another column" you will find several correct ways to do this. My favorite is "SELECT CUSTOMER_NAME FROM SALES GROUP BY CUSTOMER_NAME ORDER BY MAX(LAST_SALE_DATE) DESCENDING, CUSTOMER_NAME;" The incorrect query above will return duplicates if there are multiple records with the same name and date.

Comment: Note that your table has _columns_, not fields.

Comment: @jarlh - Yep, it's a holdover from my dBase / FoxBase days. https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/65614

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The **explain plan** for the query shows what is happening.

The parser rewrites the `fetch...` clause - it adds analytic `row_number` to the `select` list, and uses an outer query with a filter on row numbers. It pushes the `unique` directive (the `distinct` directive from your `select`) into the subquery, which is not a valid transformation; I would consider this an obvious **bug** in Oracle's implementation of `fetch...`.

The explain plan shows the step where the parser creates an inline view where it applies `unique` and it adds analytic `row_number()`. It doesn't show the projection (what columns are included in the view), and - critically - what it applies `unique` to. A little bit of experimentation suggests the answer though: it applies `unique` to the **combination** of `customer_name` and `last_sales_date`.

It's possible that this has been reported and perhaps fixed in recent versions - what is your Oracle version?

Comment: It's reproducible on [db<>fiddle 21c XE instance](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=b7bd05b5a49d2a8f1e7a99be898937d2)

Comment: @APC - I wonder if this has been reported to Oracle. I am not a paying customer (I am not a customer in any way, I am just an enthusiast playing with Oracle for my own entertainment), so I don't have access to customer support - I can't check what bugs have been reported. If anyone with access cares to check, that would be good info to share.

Comment: @mathguy - "Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.14.0.0.0"

Comment: `dbms_utility.expand_sql_text` seems to show the complete generated query. ("Seems to" because I don't know if that's the actual final transformation.) It cheekily adds the column mentioned in the `order by` clause in an inline view, then generates a `row_number()` expression in the enclosing query, and finally selects `customer_name` from the result with a `where` clause to limit the rows.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson As far as I know, `dbms_xplan.display_cursor` shows the actual execution plan. With `+PROJECTION` added to the format it depicts that `hash unique` operator is applied to the source table's projection containing the requested column and `order by` column, causing invalid results. And projection information is exactly the same what `dbms_utility` shows. See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=e091956b07a115a8c71c27036a89ce40).